# ODBC rows to columns

Tags: odbc, rows

i wanna change some rows to columns.

This is a example how i have my database now

[image]

And i wanna change it by

[image]

But i'm using a ODBC connection, if you could help me with a useful example or code guide i'll appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: you need to use PIVOT, which DBMS, also if the different values for BSC column are not known in advance, you need to use dynamic SQL and pivot

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks Rajesh, i'll search about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MAX/CASE "manual pivot" that should work on most (all?) SQL databases, something like;

```
SELECT "datetime",
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsc='bsccc2' THEN ineffective_attempts END) bsccc2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsc='bsccc3' THEN ineffective_attempts END) bsccc3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsc='bsccc4' THEN ineffective_attempts END) bsccc4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsc='bscmb2' THEN ineffective_attempts END) bscmb2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsc='bscmbo' THEN ineffective_attempts END) bscmbo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN bsc='bscva2' THEN ineffective_attempts END) bscva2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY "datetime"
ORDER BY "datetime"
```

Depending on the underlying database, you may want to change the quoting of the datetime identifier (or possibly rename the field to avoid needing to quote it).